# Calculating pi with the limit method, produces unexpected results

Tags: python, math

I am trying to do a sin operation in python and this is exactly what I'm running:

```
test = math.sin(180/1000000) * 1000000
print(test)
```

Technically, this operation gives you roughly pi (3.14159265), but in python, it gives me 179.99999902800002. Does anyone know why this is happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- The function expects the value to be in radians, not degrees

  - From the documentation, [`math.sin(x)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.sin)
- The difference between using `math` or `numpy` functions is that `numpy` will work on an `array`

  - `np.deg2rad([45, 90])` works
  - `math.radians([45, 90])` results in a `TypeError`
- If you're using single values, use the `math` function, otherwise use `numpy`.
- Wolfram Research [link](https://functions.wolfram.com/Constants/Pi/09/) to limit representations of pi.

```py
import numpy as np
import math

# convert from degrees to radians
x = np.deg2rad(180/1000000)

# make calculation
v = math.sin(x)

z = v * 1000000

# print(z)
3.1415926535846257
```

- As pointed out in a comment by [r3mainer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1679849/r3mainer), `math.sin` isn't really doing anything here.

  - For small angles, `sin(x) ≈ x`, so `sin(π/1000000) × 1000000 ≈ π`

```py
x
[out]:
3.1415926535897933e-06

v
[out]:
3.1415926535846256e-06
```

Answer (score 1):

This occurs because [`math.sin(x)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.sin) expects x to be in radians:

```
math.sin(x)
    Return the sine of x radians.
```

In order to solve this, you would need to first convert x into radians, like so:

```
test = math.sin(math.radians(180)/1000000) * 1000000
```

Outputting:

```
3.1415926535846257
```

I would not suggest using NumPy as it isn't necessary for this problem. `math.radians()` is sufficient.